# How do I use Office.JS to add invisible information to a cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, office-js

I need to add some information to an Excel cell or the same information to several selected Excel cells and that information *should not be visible.* How is this possible? I know I could add something to the properties of the whole worksheet, using the addresses (e.g. "Sheet1!A1") of the cells, but then when the table changes, the information is no more correct. I also thought I could use `addFromSelectionAsync`, but did not manage to use it, I think `addFromSelectionAsync` is not the right tool. I have seen that other AddIns are producing something like the follwoing (in different files in the saved Excel document): **[UPDATE: this is not the way to go, see my second comment below]**

```
<x15:webExtensions xmlns:xm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/2006/main">
    <x15:webExtension appRef="{12345678-...}"> 
        <xm:f>Sheet1!$A$1</xm:f>
    </x15:webExtension>
    <x15:webExtension appRef="{ABCABCAB-...}"> 
        <xm:f>Sheet1!$A$2</xm:f>
    </x15:webExtension
</x15:webExtensions>
```

```
<we:bindings>
    <we:binding id="BINDING-ID-1" type="text" appref="{12345678-...}"/> 
    <we:binding id="BINDING-ID-2" type="text" appref="{ABCABCAB-...}"/>
</we:bindings>
```

and then use `<we:properties>` (I think) to know which binding-IDs are used. Is this the way to go, will the values in `<xm:f>` automatically be updated, and how do I do this in code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aha, `addFromPromptAsync`, using the information I want to save as the ID, adds the `<x15:webExtension>` and the according `<we:binding>` like cited above. But how do I get this information from a cell?

Comment: ...Well, with the information saved as the ID in `addFromPromptAsync`, each information can only be added to exactly one cell, right? So _this is not the way to go._

Comment: OK, I am now using a UUID as the value in `addFromPromptAsync`, and setting the actual value via  `Office.context.document.settings.set` with key = the UUID and value = the actual value. Next, I need to know how to get the value for a cell.

Comment: may I know your issue has been resolved by yourself? can addFromPromptAsync and Office.context.document.settings.set unblock your scenario now?

Comment: @gingerjiang It resolved one direction, I can save the information in the Excel data, but given a cell (i.e. the accordings range) I cannot get the IDs of the according bindings. I posted the following two other questions for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69876734/problem-of-getting-the-bindings-for-an-excel-cell-via-office-js, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69879060/how-can-i-get-the-range-of-a-binding-in-office-js. In the first question, the situation is described more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

The first part was already resolved see my old comments above:

> `addFromPromptAsync`, using the information I want to save as the ID, adds the `<x15:webExtension>` and the according `<we:binding>`.

> I am now using a UUID as the value in `addFromPromptAsync`, and setting the actual value via `Office.context.document.settings.set` with key = the UUID and value = the actual value.

It was then my question:

> given a cell (i.e. the accordings range) I cannot get the IDs of the according bindings

For this second part of the problem, I added event handlers via `binding.addHandlerAsync` for the relevant Binding-IDs. Those event handler can read the binding ID from the event data.

So my problem is resolved, since I only need the Binding ID when the according cell is selected.

There is still the problem that I need to unset the binding ID that I save in a variable when another cell without that data is selected, I am using a timestamp for this, >200ms after the last binding selection event, selecting another cell deletes the info. Cf. my question [Can I set an order for the Event Handlers in Office.JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69882156/can-i-set-an-order-for-the-event-handlers-in-office-js) for that last point.