# Problem of getting the bindings for an Excel cell via Office.JS

Tags: excel, office-js

How can I get the bindings for a given Excel cell (i.e. cell range) via Office.js? I.e. something had been set via

```
Office.context.document.bindings.addFromPromptAsync(
          Office.BindingType.Text, 
          { id: "myID", promptText: ",,," }, ...
```

and I would like to get the ID "myID" (or all relevant IDs in the general case) when I have the according range.

In the saved Excel data, this relationship is clear via e.g.

```
<x15:webExtension appRef="{AF230FEC-BC8D-45C8-9022-AC416ADF52AF}"><xm:f>Sheet1!$A$1</xm:f></x15:webExtension>
```

and

```
<we:binding id="myID" type="text" appref="{AF230FEC-BC8D-45C8-9022-AC416ADF52AF}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For my use case, I now use `binding.addHandlerAsync` to add a handler that runs when the cell is selected and that I all I need, see [How do I use Office.JS to add invisible information to a cell in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69874860/how-do-i-use-office-js-to-add-invisible-information-to-a-cell-in-excel). But for a more general use case, the question remains, **but I think it is just not possible with the current API.**

Answer (score 0):

Let me double confirm is that all your issues unblocked now?

From all the three threads you posted: [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69874860/how-do-i-use-office-js-to-add-invisible-information-to-a-cell-in-excel.), [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69876734/problem-of-getting-the-bindings-for-an-excel-cell-via-office-js), [thread3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69879060/how-can-i-get-the-range-of-a-binding-in-office-js). I see you have three steps to get invisible value from range and they all work now:

1. Use range address to get related binding object. (Use `binding.addHandlerAsync`)
2. Get UUID value saved in binding object.
3. Use UUID to get real value from setting.

And you mentioned:

> But for a more general use case, the question remains, but I think it is just not possible with the current API.

Based on my knowledge, I would say yes. But if you just have several bindings, you could try iterate all the bindings to find which have same range you provide (little bit low performance).

```
async function findBinding() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const bindings = context.workbook.bindings;
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    const myRange = "Sheet1!A1:A2";
    const cnt = bindings.getCount();
    await context.sync()
    for(let i = 0; i<cnt.value; i++){
      var r = bindings.getItemAt(i).getRange();
      r.load("address");
      await context.sync();
      if(r.address==myRange){
        var item = sheet.customProperties.getItemOrNullObject(r.address);
        item.load();
        await context.sync();
        console.log(item.value);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

If you need this new feature: get binding by range address directly. Please submit a request under [this page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform), then our pm will track it and assign priority.

Thank you.