# How can I get the range of a binding in Office.JS?

Tags: excel, office-js

There used to be binding.range or binding.getRange(), but both do not function for a binding, and nothing similar is documented on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.binding. There is only the possibility to get the data of the according cell. Did this function go away and is it coming back or what is the issue here? I need it for an Excel AddIn.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the following code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.binding?view=excel-js-preview#getRange__ should work:

```
var binding = ctx.workbook.bindings.getItemAt(0);
var range = binding.getRange();
range.load('cellCount');
return ctx.sync().then(function() {
    console.log(range.cellCount);
});
```

**But** in my case, with a different code snippet (got the binding on another way), `getRange()` did *not* work, so there might be differences of how you got hands on the binding. But at least it should be possible. (I am not examining this further as I found a way not needing this functionality for my use case, cf. [How do I use Office.JS to add invisible information to a cell in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69874860/how-do-i-use-office-js-to-add-invisible-information-to-a-cell-in-excel.))