# Can I set an order for the Event Handlers in Office.JS?

Tags: excel, office-js

I am reacting to both types of events `onSelectionChanged` and `BindingSelectionChanged` in Excel, and I actually need `onSelectionChanged` to be resolved before `BindingSelectionChanged`. Is this possible, or what would be a workaround? I am using an offset now, so `onSelectionChanged` only does its job if is is >200ms after the timestamp set by `BindingSelectionChanged`. This works in practice, but is not perfect (there is no garantee that that time difference is always OK).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately currently Excel JS event order isn't guaranteed and couldn't be enforced. You may go to [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum](https://aka.ms/m365dev-suggestions) and see if this feature has already been requested or request a new feature.

Regarding your scenario, could you explain the purpose of using two `onSelectionChanged` events together? One workaround might be using just one of them and check if additional criteria are satisfied.